# COUNT and GROUP BY doesn't works as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have next query:

```
SELECT 
consumed,
count(consumed) as count,
goal
FROM (some select) alias
GROUP  BY consumed, goal
```

Instead of count of consumed rows it returns:

```
count
1
1
1
```

Comment: Add `GROUP BY consumed, goal` at the end, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly you want to count? Only consumed? Or consumed by goal? If the second option, you need group by statment.

```
SELECT  count(consumed) as count FROM (some select) alias
```

Or

```
SELECT  count(consumed) as count, goal FROM (some select) 
alias  Group by goal
```